# javadoc fails with error class file for javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding not found

Tags: java, jhipster, javadoc

I am using jhipster project on intellij using java 10.
I want to export the javadoc `tools -> generate javadoc` and i got following errors :

```
javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding not found
```

and it fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need only to add the interceptor dependency to you project and it should work

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```